# Making the Ball Change Color

Tags: css, responsive

This is a relatively simple question but I can't seem to see what I'm doing wrong here.  I just want the ball to change from red, to blue, to yellow at the 0%, %50, and %100 mark. Currently I'm not seeing any changes.

Thanks for your help,

Anna

```css
#ball {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width:50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: ball;
  animation-duration: 4s;

  @keyframes ball{
    0% {
      background-color: red;
    }

    50% {
      background-color: blue;
    }

    100% {
      background-color: yellow;
    }
  }
}
```

```html
<html>
  <body>
    <div id="ball">
  </div>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Move `@keyframes` out of your ball styles (unless you use a CSS preprocessor like SASS...)

```css
#ball {
  background-color: red;
  height: 50px;
  width: 50px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  animation-name: ball;
  animation-duration: 4s;
}

@keyframes ball {
  0% {
    background-color: red;
  }
  50% {
    background-color: blue;
  }
  100% {
    background-color: yellow;
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="ball"></div>
```

Whilst using SCSS instead, you can: [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/6L2m1pf9/1/)